# Single access to multiple blocks of diagonal block matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to access to multiple blocks of a diagonal block matrix, in MATLAB.

For example, let's say I have this (ideally sparse, but could be dense too) block matrix

```
    |A A 0 0|
    |A A 0 0|
M = |0 0 B B|
    |0 0 B B|
```

I know that, for example, one can access to the first sublock as `M(1:2,1:2)`, but I cannot find a way to access to non sequencial cells.

Is there a way to access with a single command to the submatrices A and B. Ultimately I am interested in updating a really large sparse block matrix very quick.

To clarify, in my case the block diagonals are always the same size. I know I can update them in two commands doing `M(1:2,1:2) = 1` and `M(3:4,3:4) = 2`, but can I do both in a single access? Also, I need to keep `M` as a 2D matrix since is used afterwards in matrix multiplication operations.

Comment: In order to properly answer this question you need to provide more details on what operations you want to perform on the block(s).

Comment: Updating *sparse* matrices will never be quick, because of how they are stored in memory

Comment: @AnderBiguri Agreed, but is there any way to actually update all blocks in a single access? Even if the matrix is not sparse

Comment: `M([1 3],[1 3])` ?

Comment: Are the blocks always the same size?

Comment: @beaker yes they are

Comment: Again, what does "update all blocks" mean? Are you just adding 5 to all of them? Multiplying them by 2? Are the actions on `A` different than `B`?

Comment: @excaza Update means copy arbitrary data to them. Data I have stored elsewhere.

Comment: Linear indexes are the only way of updating in a single line matrix values that do not loosely look like a square. Your case is not "square" case, as they are 2 squares, not 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your matrix `M`, with non-zero values in diagonal blocks and zeroes everywhere else (I assume), you can get an index of all the non-zero values (i.e. all the blocks) by using [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
index = find(M);
```

Using that index, you could access and update all of your blocks at once. For example, if you wanted to add 1 to all the blocks, you would do this:

```
M(index) = M(index)+1;
```

If you want to update each block to a different value, and given the size of each block, you can do this in one step using the index above and [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html). Here's an example:

```
M = [1 1 0 0; 1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1; 0 0 1 1];  % Sample matrix
index = find(M);     % Get the linear indices
blockSizes = [2 2];  % Each block is a 2-by-2
newValues = [2 3];   % New values for each block
M(index) = repelem(newValues, blockSizes.^2)

M =

     2     2     0     0
     2     2     0     0
     0     0     3     3
     0     0     3     3
```

Comment: Wow, that really worked! Actually, it even works for sparse matrices. I run the `find` command on a non-sparse matrix, then I make it sparse but I keep the indices. Then I update the whole matrix with `M(indices) = mydata`, where `mydata` is the data of my blocks. Thanks!